# CodedUI- Best way to create and use UIObject Repository( that requires minimum effort when UI changes)

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I started working with CodedUI few months before to automate a desktop Application(WPF).
Just checking out for the best ways to create a framework for my Application.

As, I have seen in other automation tools, I feel the heart of an automation framework using any tool(UI Based) is the way it's object Repository is created i.e. how well the UI objects are defined. A Cleaner and well defined Object Repository always proves to be very helpful when it comes to updating your tests.

I am trying to discover the best way to store my UIObjects so that in case of any UI changes in my Application, I have to put minimum effort to update my automation test.
Also, If an Object changes in application, updating it only at one place should solve the problem.

This can be any kind of change like :

->change in just a property(This I feel would be very easy to update in automation Test. The best and Easiet way I feel is to simply update the .uitest file(the xml file) if possible.)

->change in hierarchy and position

->entirely new object added

For the 2nd and 3rd changes, updating scripts become a difficult job, esp if the UIObject is being referred at may places, in many TestMethods, or Modules.

Also, I have generally seen that in Test Methods, Variable Declarations are done to create a reference to the UIMap objects and those variables are further used in the TestMethod Code.
So, in this case If the UI of my application changes, I will have to update the variable decalaration in each of the Test Methods. I want to reduce this effort to changing the variable decalaration only at one place. OfCourse, I cannot have all the code inside only one Test Method. One way that came to my mind is as:

Can't I have simply one common place for all these Variable decalarations. We can give a unique and understandable name to each UIObject e.g.: The decalratoions will look like:

```
UITabPage UITabPage =    this.UIMap.UISimWindow.UISelectEquipmentTabList.UITabPage;
WpfRow UIRow = this.UIMap.UISimWindow.UISelectEquipmentTabList.UITabPage.UIEquipmentDetailsTable.UIRow;
WpfText UIEquipmentTagText = this.UIMap.UISimWindow.UISelectEquipmentTabList.UITabPage.UIEquipmentDetailsTable.UIRow.UITagCell.UIEquipmentTagText;
WpfCheckBox UIEquipmentCheckBox = this.UIMap.UISimWindow.UISelectEquipmentTabList.UITabPage.UIEquipmentDetailsTable.UIRow.UICheckBoxCell.UICheckBox;
....
....
```

and use these variables wherever required. Hence, In case of any chnages also, there will be only one place where you will need to update thse objects.

But for this, These varaibles must be made STATIC. What can be problem with making these Object Variables static?

Please provide your suggestion on this topic. May be what I am thinking is not possible or practical. I just want to choose the best way to start with before I go too far with the automation scripts and realize later that my approach wasn't a good one.

Thanks in Advance,

Shruti

Answer (score 0):

Look into using descriptive programming instead of using the UIMaps.

Answer (score 0):

Make a static class with generic functions to assist. Going to give you some examples of how to set it up.

For example:

```
public WinWindow parentwin(string ParentControlName)
            {
            var parentwin = new WinWindow();
            parentwin.SearchProperties.Add("Control Name", ParentControlName);

            return parentwin;
            }
        public WinWindow childwin(string ChildWinControlName, string ParentControlName)
            {
            var childwin = new WinWindow(parentwin(ParentControlName));
            childwin.SearchProperties.Add("Control Name", ChildWinControlName);

            return childwin;
            }
        public WinButton button(string ButtonName,string ChildWinControlName, string ParentControlName)
            {
            var childwin = childwin(ChildWinControlName,ParentControlName);
            var button = new WinButton(childwin);
            button.SearchProperties.Add("Name", ButtonName);
            }
        public void ClickButton(string ButtonName,string ChildWinControlName, string ParentControlName)
            {
            var button = button(ButtonName,ChildWinControlName,ParentControlName);
            Mouse.Click(button);
            }
         public void ChangeFocus(WinWindow NewFocus)
            {
            var NewFocus = new NewFocus();
            NewFocus.SetFocus();
            }
         public void ChangeFocus(WinWindow NewFocusChild, string c)
            {

             var a = new NewFocus();
             a.SetFocus();
            }
ChangeFocus(childwin("WelcomeForm", "MainForm");
ClickButton("&OK", "WelcomeForm", "MainForm");
```